# Storing values from loop and comparing them every time run the script

Tags: bash, bitcoin

#### Description

Hello,

I'm trying to loop over certain commands and save their outputs into a file, and while looping through those commands, also check the file which we saved their outputs so we can compare them from the file while looping the commands at the same time. In the end, check if the looped commands' outputs match with the previously saved outputs in that file. *(Also check if the file doesn't contain the output and add it into the file so we can later use it to compare again)*

This is my main script which loops through the said commands which are located inside `/usr/local/bin/` so I can run them directly from the shell.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
wallets=`find /usr/local/bin/ -iname '*-cli'`

for i in $wallets; do
    current_blocks=`$I getblockcount`
    coin_name=${i:15:-4} # I use `:15:-4` here to cut the path and the last 4 characters. (For example it's `/usr/local/bin/bitcoin-cli` so I change it to `bitcoin` only
    echo $coin_name $current_blocks
    echo $coin_name $current_blocks >> blocks.log
done
```

And this echo gives us exactly this (assuming there are 2 items in the `$wallets`;

```
bitcoin 1457824
litecoin 759345
```

And this is the while loop I will -presumably- be using to read from the file;

```bsh
while read line ; do
    set $line
    echo $1 $2
done < blocks.log
```

Which will also gives us this output when we run it;

```
bitcoin 1457824
litecoin 759345
```

So since I have these 2 code bits, now I want to merge them into a single script so I can both use the first code bit to loop through commands and also compare them with the `blocks.log` file. *(Again, also check if the file doesn't contain the output and add it into the file so we can later use it to compare again)*.

#### My first (and failed) approach;

```bsh
for i in $wallets; do

    current_blocks=`$i getblockcount`
    coin_name=${i:15:-4}

    while read line; do
        set $line
        if [ "$1" == "$coin_name" ]; then
            echo "File contains the coin_name, compare the blocks now"
            if (( "$current_blocks" >= "$2" )); then
                echo "Current blocks are greater than the saved blocks"
                echo "Saving the new blocks count now"
                sed -i "s/$1/$1 $current_blocks/" blocks.log
            else
                echo "Current blocks are less than or equals to saved blocks"
            fi
        else
            echo "File does not contain the coin_name, adding it now"
            echo "$coin_name $current_blocks" >> blocks.log
        fi
    done < blocks.log

done
```

#### My second (another failed) attempt;

```bsh
for i in $wallets; do

    current_blocks=`$i getblockcount`
    coin_name=${i:15:-4}

    read line < blocks.log
    set $line
    if [ "$1" == "$coin_name" ]; then
        echo "File contains the coin_name, compare the blocks now"
        if (( "$current_blocks" >= "$2" )); then
            echo "Current blocks are greater than the saved blocks"
            echo "Saving the new blocks count now"
            # sed -i "s/$1/$1 $current_blocks/" blocks.log
        else
            echo "Current blocks are less than or equals to saved blocks"
        fi
    else
        echo "File does not contain the coin_name, adding it now"
        echo "$coin_name $current_blocks" >> blocks.log
    fi

done
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can't you use your _simple_ script and then post-process the data in the file with another _simple_ script?

Comment: I don't know, can I?

Comment: @Kusalananda, why did you delete your answer?

Comment: I don't currently have time to work on it, and since it doesn't fulfil your needs anyway, I deleted it. I may pick it up in the future to make it better match your original ideas, but not now.

Comment: It's just asking for trouble to be modifying a file that you are currently reading. This should be done in two steps as @Kusalananda suggests. In place is for avoiding making a second copy, not for doing things in parallel. I'm having a hard time visualizing what's in blocks.log. It's not sorted, so how do you know the entry you're looking for will be the one you see when you read each line? In your second attempt, line will always start with the first line in blocks.log. Basically, you need to make a very simple example and run it through by hand on paper to see what it does.